# How are Kleenex Tissues Infused

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Kleenex tissues are infused with long lasting scents - their scent is released when crushed. How does this work? I's like to know how to reproduce similar effect for another purpose. Who would be the person who could develop this for me? A Chemist - A Pharmacist?

Comment: [This](https://www.kleenex.com/en-us/faq) FAQ from the manufacturer will get you somewhere, but I suggest contacting them directly to resolve your question.

Comment: I think that the company might be not so eager to share their trade secrets. I guess that they use microencapsulation similar to the 'scratch and sniff' stuff. A chemist with the experience in the pharmaceutical industry may be the right person to develop your product.